# JIRA REST API - Basic Authentication

Tags: curl, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to use curl to retrieve jira issue from my company server without any luck so far.

I've tested both examples described here [JIRA REST API Example - Basic Authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication) with no success. I base64 encoded my user and password as described in the "Supplying Basic Auth headers" example and entered the url for the issue I want to get. I tested the url in browser I get the json document so the url is correct.

This is what my command looks like

> someuser@somehost:~$ curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic base64encodedstringhere -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.acme.com/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-666

And I then get prompt with ">" but no json document. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't encode the user name and password - curl already handles this!

```
curl -u "username:password" -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.acme.com/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-666
```

If you need to specify basic authentication, do it like this:

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic usernamesndpasswordbase64 -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.acme.com/rest/api/2/issue/KEY-666
```

where the username-and-password string is username:password encoded together e.g. via

```
echo username:password | base64 | sed /Cg==/s///
```

Both of these work for me on curl under Cygwin.

Comment: You probably want to use API tokens instead of actual password for this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html

Comment: @Kristofer agreed that that is a better approach, but the question was about using basic authentication.

Comment: Agreed! That's why I wrote a comment instead of another answer. Maybe I should have commented on the question instead but I don't think those are read very often

Comment: Doesn't work on my side either. Getting a > like initial question is asking.

Comment: @LudwigS this warrants a new question with all your details, exact command, environment...

Comment: Hey James, yes, Win 10 Ubuntu Linux 4.4.0, curl 7.68.0; command: curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic USERPASSSTRING -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.ACME.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJECT%20order%20by%20created%20ASC&startAt=0&maxResults=10 > Issues_10.json -- This query just gives a ">" as result, have to cancel with ctrl+c

Comment: You’re missing a quotation mark in your example. I still recommend opening a new question since you are asking about this answer instead of the OP.